# regex with delimiters for getting value

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need to get the value 20 as below:

```
this is expired time is (second) 20
max time in the system       1048576
```

My regex must return the value 20.

i have tried as below:

```
this is expired time is\s+(\d+)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `this is expired time is.* \K\d+$`? `(?<=this is expired time is.* )\d+$`?

Comment: (?i)this is expired time is\s+\S+\s+(\d+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^this is expired time is \(second\) (\d+)
```